# "IndexError: string index out of range" cause?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to learn Python, but I'm stuck on an error that I don't know why I'm getting.
With the code below, it returns an error for Line 2: `IndexError: string index out of range`.

note: The # on the last function call is just to isolate the issue.

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    elif message[0] != message[-1]:
        return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
#print(first_and_last(""))
```

If I change Line 3 to False. The code runs without the error.

```
 def first_and_last(message):
        if message[0] == message[-1]:
            return False
        elif message[0] != message[-1]:
            return False
    
    print(first_and_last("else"))
    print(first_and_last("tree"))
    #print(first_and_last(""))
```

I know I'm missing something fundamental here, would someone be willing to point out what is actually going on, so I can understand why the error is happening?

Edit: Okay, I think including the working code distracted from the issue. I get that an empty string will cause an error, but the error I cannot work out is happening in line 2 without trying to process an empty string, but by simply changing the return value in line 2, to False, the error goes away

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python "IndexError: string index out of range" (Beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308057/python-indexerror-string-index-out-of-range-beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the empty string doesn't have anything at index `0`. Just as `"a"` doesn't have anything at index `>1`.

A little trick to avoid the error or even explicit size checking, is to use **slicing** instead of **indexing**. This is because slicing will never raise an error, **even if the index is out of range**:

```
>>> "abc"[0]
'a'
>>> "abc"[:1]
'a'
>>> ""[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> ""[:1]
''
```

So as long as you consider the empty string to fulfill the condition, you can do:

```py
def first_and_last(message):
    if message[:1] == message[-1:]:
        return True
    elif message[:1] != message[-1:]:
        return False
```

Or, in short:

```py
def first_and_last(message):
    return message[:1] == message[-1:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think including the working code clouded the issue a little.
The function call on the empty string was excluded when the error occurred.
The error was on line 2 of the code and stopped when changing the Boolean in Line 3, from True to False.

Comment: Your code as is doesn't raise any error (with the commented line)...

Answer (score 0):

An empty string (or any iterable) doesn't have anything at indexes 0 (start) or -1 (end) and trying to get anything from those indexes causes an IndexError. If it's a requirement to not generate an exception for an empty string, you should test for it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to fetch data from the empty string.

If `message = ''`  then `message[0]` and `message[-1]` doesn't work

you can check with a simple code:

```
message = ''
print(message[0])
#print(message[-1])
```

Output:

```
print(message[-1])
IndexError: string index out of range
```